# Permit user roles to see node (not via view) based on a taxonomy

Tags: 7, users

I have some content type with a term reference field (think a magazine site where news are linked to a category).

I must block the node view for a user role, but I don't want to set this access for single node (like tac/tac_lite do), but for single category linked to the node (via term reference field). For example I want that role "FOO" can see node of category "BAR" but not nodes of category "XYZ", where "BAR" and "XYZ" are terms od f the same vocabulary.

My idea is this:

- add a select list field to the vocabolary's fields (and the allowed
  values will be the role's ID) so that I can link role to each
  category/term
- when a user try to access to a node, I check (via hook_node_access() ) that current user's role is available in the node's category fields (that I have setted in previos step).

Is there a better way ?

M.

Answer (score 0):

You can do your own implementation of hook_node_access in a custom module. It passes you the node and the user object, so you can check for certain criteria, and limit access appropriately.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7